# installing the package xtsExtra on a windows machine

Tags: r, xts

I am having a bit of difficulty installing the R package `xtsExtra` on a windows machine..., and not too sure whats wrong...

```
> install.packages("xtsExtra", ,repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xtsExtra’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
Error in install.packages : argument is missing, with no default
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.0
> install.packages("xtsExtra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xtsExtra’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HMaeda/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘xtsExtra’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xtsExtra’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
> require(xtsExtra)
Loading required package: xtsExtra
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘xtsExtra’
```

As ever any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future visitors, see [this new, more comprehensive post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the Warning says, it is available as a source package, but not as a binary, so specify `type=source`.  This worked for me on a Windows box:

```
install.packages("xtsExtra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
```